# Как через System.Diagnostics.Process.Start открыть файл на клиенте?

Tags: c#, asp.net

У пользователя есть список файлов разного расширения. Когда он два раза кликает на файл, должна открываться соответствующая программа просмотра файла.

Делаю это так:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(LocalFileManager.workingFolder, localFilePath));
```

Когда сервис установлен на другой машине, клиент ничего не увидит.

Как сделать чтобы соответствующая программа открывалась на клиенте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал так:

Метод WebApi:

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetFilePath(string fileName, Guid categoryId, Guid userId)
    {
        using (var _client = new DataServiceClient("epData"))
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Domain != "")
            {
                _client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.Domain + "\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.Login;
                _client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
            }
            _client.SetCurrentUser(userId);
            var category = _client.GetAttachmentCategory(categoryId);
            LocalFileManager.SetWorkingFolder(category);
        }

        var serverName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
        var result = Path.Combine(serverName, LocalFileManager.shortWorkingFolder, fileName);

        return result;
    }
```

Т.е метод GetFilePath просто возвращает url путь к фалу на сервере.

А потом через Angularjs все как показано в этом примере (просто copy/paste):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080018/download-file-from-an-asp-net-web-api-method-using-angularjs

В IE 11 тоже работает как надо, если сделать как показано в **Internet Explorer 11 Support (Fixed).**

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, клиент ничего не увидит, потому что ваш код выполняется на стороне сервера. Для открытия вам нужно использовать средства JS (посмотрите, например, [там](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376745/does-html5-allow-you-to-interact-with-local-client-files-from-within-a-browser)).